# Start:applet not initialized when trying to open a frame in an applet

Tags: java

I ran across a code in the book java 2 by Herbert Schildt .Here is the code .

```
import java.applet.Applet;
```

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

```
public class SampleFrame extends Frame
{
    public SampleFrame(String title)
    {
        super(title);
        MyWindowAdapter wAdapter = new MyWindowAdapter(this);
        addWindowListener(wAdapter);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString("this is in the frame window", 10, 40);
    }

}
class MyWindowAdapter extends WindowAdapter
{
    SampleFrame sampleFrame;
    public MyWindowAdapter(SampleFrame sampleFrame)
    {
        this.sampleFrame = sampleFrame;
    }
    public void WindowClosing(WindowEvent we)
    {
        sampleFrame.setVisible(false);
    }
}
class MyApplet extends Applet
{
    Frame f;
    public void init()
    {
        f = new SampleFrame("a frame window");
        f.setSize(250, 250);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void start()
    {
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void stop()
    {
        f.setVisible(false);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString("this is an applet window", 10, 20);
    }
}
```

according to the book it should start an applet which should start a frame . But when the applet starts in the status bar it say "start:applet not initilized"
why so?

I did create applets without declaring my derived applet class as public like this

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;


class MouseEvents extends Applet implements MouseListener,
        MouseMotionListener
{
    String msg = "";
    int mouseX = 0 ,mouseY = 0 ,count=0;
    Boolean tPU ;
    private Point myPoint;

    public MouseEvents()
    {
        myPoint = new 
                Point();

    }

    public void init()
    {
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mouseX = arg0.getX();
        mouseY = arg0.getY();
        msg = "*";
        myPoint = arg0.getPoint();
        tPU = arg0.isPopupTrigger();
        count = arg0.getClickCount();
        arg0.translatePoint(100, 100);
        myPoint = arg0.getPoint();

        showStatus("dragging mouse at " + arg0.getX() + ", " +arg0.getY());
        showStatus("popUps ?"+tPU);
        showStatus("dragging mouse at " + myPoint.x + ", " +myPoint.y);
        showStatus("dragging mouse at " + myPoint.x + ", " +myPoint.y);
        showStatus("dragging mouse at " + myPoint.x + ", " +myPoint.y);

        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        showStatus("moving mouse at " + arg0.getX() + ", " +arg0.getY());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mouseX=0;
        mouseY=10;
        msg="mouse clicked";
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mouseX=0;
        mouseY=10;
        msg="mouse entered";
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mouseX=0;
        mouseY=20;
        msg="mouse exited";
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mouseX = e.getX();
        mouseY = e.getY();
        msg = "mouse pressed down";
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mouseX = e.getX();
        mouseY = e.getY();
        msg = "mouse released up";
        repaint();
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString(msg, mouseX, mouseY);
    }

}
```

Comment: To be honest, I think you're wasting your time reading a book about Java 2.  Java 2 was superseded by Java 5 in 2004, which was a much more sophisticated language.  We're now onto Java 7, and some people are even using Java 8.  Nobody uses Java 2 any more, and many of the techniques that you learn from that book will be out-of-date and will not be very useful.

Comment: i searched for java 7/8 in a local market here in Pakistan and i didnt find it any where . searched for it on the net for a free book.Still not found.Would you be or some one elsse kind enough to give me a direct link of the ebook of latest edition only by Herbert Schildt ?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my last comment because I'm unsure of the copyright status of the book that I linked to.  I'm not sure whether it's legal for me to link to it here, but I do recommend "Thinking in Java" by Bruce Eckel.  The fourth edition covers Java 6, which is "close enough" to current to be useful.  You may be able to find it online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the applet console you should see the rest of the error

```
MyApplet.class is not public or has no public constructor.
```

i.e. declare the class as `public`

```
public class MyApplet extends Applet {
```

Comment: when i declare it public it says that a public class should be defined seperatly.Besides why did'nt Herbert Schildt notice that? I mean no offence but if that was the reason why did'nt the book said so?

Comment: and i created applets when i was learning applets and handling mouse/keyboard events , i didnt declare extended applet class as public and they did work fine .Why should i declare them public here then?

Comment: The applet framework relies on the class being public to be instantiated (through reflection) - never seen an applet to work being declared otherwise :)

Comment: i have edited my post with the code i used to create applets before without declaring my derived applet class as public

Comment: seems you're confusing having a `public` constructor with declaring the class itself `public`

Comment: No, @Reimeus, she's just trying to follow what you told her to do.

Comment: And she's pointed out that in the past, she's had a working applet class (MouseEvents) that was not declared as public.  Sure, it's worth a try, but I'm wondering how likely it is that this is actually her problem.

Comment: Frankly, I really wish that the publishers of books like this one would test all of their code more thoroughly before publishing the book.  This happens far too often.  So many big, heavy books come with big heavy lists of errors.

Comment: i got the solution and actually you guys are right about the class being public . but the thing is the book dosent suggest it to be public neither it declares it public (btw the book is of a very reliable author Herbert Schildt) but the thing is its java2 and now a days its java7 ,this might be the issue .Any ways i got what i was looking for and really thanks a lot guys